# How to Edit and Delete Get/Post API Data in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I can not under Stand How to Edit or Delete  Get/Post API data in Ionic.
I'm tried to Edit And Delete ionic Post/Get data using API.
please some body help me in this  ionic operation. it's argent to me.
#huge_request

Answer (score 0):

First in an Ionic/Angular project you'll need to import HttpClient in your TS file or service.
And then use it in your function.

```
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

You need to understand that you'll get a result as an Observable (https://angular.io/guide/observables). For your function to work, you'll need to subscribe to it.

Example you have a function in a service.ts file:

```
getData(id: string) {

 return this.http.get(url, option or what the api need)
 // you might need to use observable manipulation like pipe or map to get the data you want


}
```

In the ts file you use the service :

```
 import {service} from 'Service'

 constructor (private service: Service) {}


 function() {
    service.getData(id).subscribe(res => {
     console.log(res)

    })
 }
```

Comment: there is show a error   "Property 'subcribe' does not exist on type 'void'."

Comment: sorry forgot to return it. "return this.http.get. etc"